# Getting Error Using Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I am getting an error using the RegisterExternalLogin control from the Visual Studio templates. After choosing login from Twitter, Twitter seems to process the login ok and then tries to load the response page and then the error occurs.

The error seems to be related to EntityFrameworks after the login method being called from the Microsoft.Aspnet.Membership.OpenAuth dll but that's about all I know.

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Here is the error message:

> [MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'.]
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.EFOpenAuthMembershipDatabase.EnsureDatabaseCreated(DbContext
>   db) +0
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.EFOpenAuthMembershipDatabase.GetMembershipUserName(String
>   providerName, String providerUserId, Boolean updateLastUsed) +221
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.OpenAuthManager.Login(HttpContextBase
>   context, String providerName, String providerUserId, Boolean
>   createPersistentCookie) +128
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.OpenAuth.Login(String
>   providerName, String providerUserId, Boolean createPersistentCookie)
>   +198    FinModelControls.Account.RegisterExternalLogin.ProcessProviderResult()
>   +594

Comment: I think there seems to be an incompatibility between the login controls provided by the old templates and EntityFrameworks 6 which I think the Membership.OpenAuth dll now uses. Rather than solve the problem I decided to just move to the login controls provided by VS 2013. They use different dlls and work fine with everything I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Having similar exception, submitted a Conect bug.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811035/microsoft-aspnet-membership-openauth-is-not-compatible-with-entity-framework-6

**Solution:** Make sure you're using latest v 2.0.0 Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth package, not 1.0.1.

Comment: How do I download the AspNet package? I searched and couldn't find anywhere in VS 2012 :/